# Intersection of vector of pair c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have the following vectors:

```
 vector<unsigned> A,B1;
 vector<pair<unsigned,unsigned> > B2;
```

I want to perform the intersection of `(A,B1)` and then the intersection of `(A,B2)`. I want to then perform the union of the two intersection results. Vectors `A` and `B1` contain sorted unsigned integers and vector `B2` contains pairs of `(start,end)` values. Example vectors `A` and `B2`, and their intersection vector is shown below:

```
   vector<unsigned> A(2,4,6,8,9,10,34,74,79,81,89,91,95);
   vector<pair<unsigned,unsigned> > B2={ {2, 3}, {29, 40}, {60, 85} };
   vector<unsigned> intersection; //result of intersection of A and B2 -> Procedure of performing intersection is explained below
   //intersection=(2,34,74,79,81);
```

`2` is in intersection as `2` is in `{2,3}`. Similarly `34` is in intersection as `34` lies between `{29,40}`. Similarly `74`, `79`, `81` are in intersection as they lie within `B2`'s last element `{60,85}`'s range.

Is there some efficient way by which I may get the same results as:

(1). intersection `A` and `B1`; 
(2). intersection of `A` and `B2`; 
(3). union of the two intersections performed in step 1 and 2 (i.e. intersection `(A,B1)` and `(A,B2)`)

Comment: Yes there is: write your own efficient code to do this. There is no existing function in the C++ library that implements this highly specific algorithm, so it is up to you to write it, for your own code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

After re-reading the question I realised that you probably wanted to do all three operations in one.

We can reduce the number of iterations of the outer loop to one and remove one inner loop by composing three functions into one and returning a tuple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>


std::tuple<std::vector<unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned>>
find_everything(const std::vector<unsigned>& a,
                const std::vector<std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> >& b1,
                const std::vector<std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> >& b2)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> r1, r2, both;

    for (auto x : a)
    {
        auto either = false;
        auto i = std::find_if(std::begin(b1),
                              std::end(b1),
                              [x](const auto& range)
                              { return x >= range.first && x < range.second; });
        if (i != std::end(b1)) {
            either = true;
            r1.push_back(x);
        }

        i = std::find_if(std::begin(b2),
                              std::end(b2),
                              [x](const auto& range)
                              { return x >= range.first && x < range.second; });
        if (i != std::end(b2)) {
            either = true;
            r2.push_back(x);
        }

        if (either) {
            both.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(r1), std::move(r2), std::move(both));
}



int main()
{

    using namespace std;

    vector<unsigned> A { 2,4,6,8,9,10,34,74,79,81,89,91,95 };
    vector<pair<unsigned,unsigned> > B1={ {4, 5}, {8, 10}, {90, 99} };
    vector<pair<unsigned,unsigned> > B2={ {2, 3}, {29, 40}, {60, 85} };

    auto results = find_everything(A, B1, B2);
    const auto& r1 = std::get<0>(results);
    const auto& r2 = std::get<1>(results);
    const auto& both = std::get<2>(results);
    copy(begin(r1), end(r1), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, ", "));
    cout << endl;

    copy(begin(r2), end(r2), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, ", "));
    cout << endl;

    copy(begin(both), end(both), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, ", "));
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
4, 8, 9, 91, 95,
2, 34, 74, 79, 81,
2, 4, 8, 9, 34, 74, 79, 81, 91, 95,
```

Further work:

There are two immediately obvious improvements we could make if the datasets are large:

1. Since A, B1 and B2 are sorted, we can track "current" match iterators, reducing the search space on each match or non-match (this starts to argue for `std::lower_bound`)
2. or if A is significantly larger than B1 and B2, we could parallelise the search.

Have fun :)